# Getting error: Could not find session for *blob_key*

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

Im trying to make a form where users can upload a file. And I have a form that takes the users arguments and posts them to the UploadHandler that is mapped to the url that is passed as parameter to the renderfunction. It works up to the point that it renders the form, but when submitting the file it redirects me to a blank page and the console shows me the error:

```
 ERROR    2013-03-17 11:53:30,769 dev_appserver_blobstore.py:404] Could not find session       for ahhkZXZ-a3Vyc3NhbW1hbmZhdHRuaW5nYXJyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgxDA
 INFO     2013-03-17 11:53:30,779 dev_appserver.py:3104] "POST /_ah/upload/ahhkZXZ-   a3Vyc3NhbW1hbmZhdHRuaW5nYXJyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgxDA HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Im still new at this but I can't seem to find whats going on. I understand that the mappings somehow f***s up, but still I don't understand why it doesn't redirect me to the correct handler (SummaryHandler)?

The class that serves the form for file upload:

```
class CreateHandler(BaseHandler):
def get(self):
    self.render('create.html', upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload'))
```

The html-form ('create.html'):

```
<h2 class="main-title">Upload a file!</h2>  
<form action="{{upload_url}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>
        <div>Upload:</div> 
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf"><br> 
    </label>
    <div class="error">
        {{file_error}}
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
 </form>
```

The uploadhandler that takes the form args:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  
    blob_info = upload_files[0]

    #validation of form-vars
    have_error=False
    file_data=dict()
    if not (blob_info.content_type == 'application/pdf'):
        file_data['file_error']="You can only upload files in pdf-format."
        have_error=True
    if have_error:
        self.render('create.html', **file_data)
    else:
        #'parent' is just some stuff for organising the database. 
        #Not important in this context
        the_file = A_File(parent = summary_key(),   
                          file_key=str(blob_info.key()))
        the_file.put()
        if the_file:
            self.redirect('/summary/%s' % str(the_file.key().id()))
        else:
            _error="Could not find the file"
            self.render('welcome.html', error=_error)
```

The application handlers and their mappings:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
(r'/', WelcomeHandler),
(r'/create', CreateHandler),
(r'/upload', UploadHandler),
(r'/summary/(\d+)', SummaryHandler) #I have not included this handler in the text
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Did you manage to run the bare-bone complete example? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App

Comment: Yes I did, do you think it has something to do with my problem?

Comment: If the example worked then it has nothing to do with the example.. check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the fact that this session expired or it was used. The urls that created using `create_upload_url` have an expiration (I think 10 min). Before actually posting you might want to refresh that URL using JavaScript.

Also if for any reason the file was uploaded in the Blobstore you won't be able to use the same URL again, it is only good for one request (could have multiple files though).

In your example, try to remove all the file specific checks, try to upload something and check through the administrative console in the Datastore Viewer if you have any blobs or session keys. This can be accessed through this URL:

```
 http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Im uploading the blob in the blobstore and can find both the blobinfo and the uploadblobsessions which corresponds to all the uploaded files. The thing that I dont understand is how to get the file from the blobstore if I can't use the same url again. If only you can point me to a direction where I can read about it, I would be greatful.

Comment: Well the direction is in the example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob When you want to get the file from the blobstore you are using the blobkey that you should store somewhere.

Comment: Well thats in fact what Im trying to achieve. But the problem is the  "upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')"-line. Im using this upload_url as the action of the form, exactly as the example but the UploadHandler does not map to the url that I get. In the urlmapping, I have only "/upload" not "/_ah/upload/*blobkey*. Do you think I should rewrite the mapping, although I have not found it in any example I have seen. Sorry for bothering you so much with these newbie questions...

Comment: @patriques I guess you solved it already.. in the link that I provided you should find all your answers.

Comment: Yes I did, thank you. But really without understanding why it suddently started working. Well sometimes, that is how it plays out. :-P. If I could ask a last question? Now it redirects me properly when I need it to, but when the file is not as i require in my test "if not (blob_info.content_type == 'application/pdf')" it dont render the "welcome.html"page as I intend to make it do. It only shows me the empty page and the same url as before: http://localhost:8080/_ah/upload/*blob_key*? Can you figure out why. Anyway, thank you for all your help. You have been great.

Comment: @patriques instead of rendering it there.. you should redirect to the welcome page and possibly log the error. You could also check at one point a bit more complicated example but a fully working solution for uploading stuff on gae: http://upload.gae-init.appspot.com/resource/upload/